# How to properly set environment variable TERM in CLion

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, clion

Using CLion on OSX, I'm creating a simple console app in which I want to do a `system("clear")`. When I'm running the app in the OSX terminal, it works without issue. When I run it using the CLion terminal, the `system("clear")` fails with message :

> TERM environment variable not set.

I first tried to manually set it in my `cmakelists.txt` file without success by doing

```
set(ENV{TERM} "xterm-256color")
```

I then tried to manually set it (followed by full restart) in CLion settings for both Console and CMake sections in Build, Execution, Deployment using the following key/value pair (Environment option):

```
 TERM      xterm-256color
```

In my OSX terminal, doing a `env | grep TERM` prints out

> TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=388
>
> TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
>
> TERM=xterm-256color

What am I missing? I unfortunately can't find it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found the fix. You must add the Environment Variable `TERM=xterm-256color` not in the Console or the CMake config bug in the your Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: This is a great answer for environment variables needed at runtime. However before a build, when importing a CMake project, the correct place to put environment variables seems to be IntelliJ > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > CMake > Environment. Just a small addition that I recently discovered.