# How do I fix opening terminal error with c++ ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses, terminfo

I'm using CLion 2018.2.6 on MacOS. I'm trying to use ncurses but getting the error "Error opening terminal: unknown." I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help appreciated. Code below.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ncurses.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
     initscr();
     clear();
     printw("Seems legit!");
     refresh();
     getch();
     endwin();
}
```

Comment: You get that error because the environment variable `term` is not set in CLions console. [How to properly set environment variable TERM in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263743/how-to-properly-set-environment-variable-term-in-clion) might help.

Answer (score 2):

The [`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Unset-TERM-Variable) manual page mentions this:

> **Unset TERM Variable**
>
> If  the  TERM variable is missing or empty, initscr uses the value ***"unknown"***, which normally corresponds to a terminal entry with the generic
>   (gn)  capability.   Generic  entries  are  detected  by  setupterm (see
>   curs_terminfo(3x)) and cannot be used for full-screen operation.  Other
>   implementations may handle a missing/empty TERM variable differently.

Also, depending on how your system is configured, ncurses may not even find the terminal database, e.g., if it is installed in a different location than the compiled-in default location.  Like TERM, that can be fixed using the [TERMINFO](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO) or [TERMINFO_DIRS](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO_DIRS) environments.  As an additional complication, MacOS by default uses case-insensitive filesystems, and ncurses uses a different directory organization for that.  The [`term(5)`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html#h2-PORTABILITY) manual page mentions that:

> A  small  number  of  terminal descriptions use uppercase characters in
>   their names.  If  the  underlying  filesystem  ignores  the  difference
>   between  uppercase and lowercase, ncurses represents the "first character" of the terminal name used as the intermediate level of a directory
>   tree in (two-character) hexadecimal form.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of terminfo folder in the application running system and the same path in your application like this,

Ex:- setenv("TERMINFO","/usr/share/terminfo", 1);

It working.